# Principalcontext configuration with web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, active-directory-group, principalcontext

I'm able to get group memberships using following code:

```
PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain", "administrator", "Password"))
```

I would like to move this administrator username password in **web.config** so that I dont have to make changes to the code when the password changes.

Comment: You should change your AppPool account to `Network Service` and then just use `PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain")` without providing any username and password

Comment: @harvey kwok : many thanks. finnaly I solved the problem.